# xsl remove all non-numeric characters and leading 1

Tags: xslt, transformation

I need to convert incoming phone number strings to a standardized format that does not have any non-numeric characters and strips off the leading number if it is 1.

For example:

"+1 (222) 333-4444 x 5555" becomes "22233344445555"

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

**I. XSLT 1.0 solution:**

**This transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output method="text"/>

 <xsl:template match="text()">
  <xsl:variable name="vnumsOnly" select=
  "translate(., translate(.,'0123456789',''), '')
  "/>

  <xsl:value-of select=
  "substring($vnumsOnly, (substring($vnumsOnly,1,1)='1') +1)"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on this XML document**:

```
<t>"+1 (222) 333-4444 x 5555</t>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result**:

```
22233344445555
```

**Explanation**:

1. The expression: `translate(.,'0123456789','')` is evaluated to a string that contains all non-numeric characters in the current node.
2. We use 1. above in the expression:

   translate(., translate(.,'0123456789',''), '')

and this evaluates to a string where all non-numeric characters from the current node are deleted.

.3. The expression: `(substring($vnumsOnly,1,1)='1') +1)"` evaluates to `2` if the first character of `$vnumsOnly` is `'1'` and it evaluates to `1` if the starting character isn't '1'.

.4. We use 3. in the following expression:

```
substring($vnumsOnly, (substring($vnumsOnly,1,1)='1') +1)
```

which evaluates to the same string `$vnumsOnly` if it doesn't start with '1' and it evaluates to its substring starting from the 2nd character, if the first character is '1'.

---

**II. XPath 2.0 solution:**

**Just use**:

```
replace(replace(., '[^0-9]', ''), '^1', '')
```

The inner replace removes all characters that aren't 0 through 9 (digits). The outer replace removes the leading 1 (if it exists).

Comment: Thanks!  This works perfectly.  I really appreciate the explanation too.

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev does this also work for the translate above?

`translate($phone,'0123456789'+$phone,'0123456789')`

instead of 

`translate(., translate(.,'0123456789',''), '')`

which is better?

Comment: @Nate, The expression you propose probably will produce the correct result. However, it can require extensive memory -- especially when the input string is significantly long. The "double-translate" method doesn't construct a second string that is longer than the input string.

Answer (score 1):

This stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:variable name="vPhone"
          select="translate(Phone,translate(Phone,'0123456789',''),'')"/>
        <xsl:value-of 
                select="substring($vPhone, 1 + starts-with($vPhone,'1'))"/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

With this input:

```
<Phone>+1 (222) 333-4444 x 5555</Phone>
```

Output:

```
22233344445555
```

Comment: @Alejandro: +1 for a perfect solution that was submitted even a few seconds before mine. :)

Answer (score 1):

replace(replace(., '[^1-9]', ''), '^1', '') - I am responding to this... Instead of [^1-9]... Use [^0-9] otherwise any 0's in the phone number get deleted. But other than that this fixed my Workday integration issue great!

Answer (score 0):

You could use nested [replace](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-replace) xpath functions. The insider would change the first digit to space if it is 1, the outsider would change nondigits to space.