# Change text inside specific XML Tags (get rid of non-numeric chars)

Tags: xml, regex, xslt, xslt-1.0

The task is to get rid of any non-numeric character in the following `CustomerIdentity` element inside an XML file:

```
<ns2:TaxAtSource institutionID="#SG">
    <ns2:CantonID>SG</ns2:CantonID>
    <ns2:CustomerIdentity>CHE123.456 </ns2:CustomerIdentity>
</ns2:TaxAtSource>
```

I tried sed (which would be elegant, but as the nonnumeric characters can be anywhere between `CustomerIdentity` tags, is getting a bit hairy with the regex). I also tried XSLT, but the namespace ns2 is making troubles in identifying the tag (nonreferenced namespace).
So if anyone has a working solution to process the XML file to look as follows (the rest should be unchanged):

```
<ns2:TaxAtSource institutionID="#SG">
    <ns2:CantonID>SG</ns2:CantonID>
    <ns2:CustomerIdentity>123456</ns2:CustomerIdentity>
</ns2:TaxAtSource>
```

this would be very much appreciated. A collegue suggested using AWK or ruby, but this boils down to regex too, I think.

EDIT: I already tried the following XSLT from [xsl remove all non-numeric characters and leading 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3821741/xsl-remove-all-non-numeric-characters-and-leading-1):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output method="text"/>

<xsl:template match="text()">
    <xsl:variable name="vnumsOnly" select=
    "translate(., translate(.,'0123456789',''), '')
    "/>

    <xsl:value-of select=
    "substring($vnumsOnly, (substring($vnumsOnly,1,1)='1') +1)"/>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

but that didn't quite work out.

Comment: What do you mean by "non-referenced namespace"? If the namespace prefix does not have a definition, then your data does not qualify as well-formed XML and is _not_ an XML file. Further, XSLT will not accept it as input.

Comment: @codeninja Namespace file?

Comment: @mathis, thanks for point out my mistake, i deleted my comment. i thought it could be the dtd problem so that i mentioned to reconfirm the file directory. but now i realised that its a fault of wrong/non-declared namespace declaration in the root directory

Comment: [xml namespaces](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_namespaces.asp)

Comment: Well, the XML code is just a snippet, it begins indeed with: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ns4:DeclareSalaryConsumer xmlns:ns4="http://www.swissdec.ch/schema/sd/20130514/SalaryDeclarationConsumerServiceTypes"
                           xmlns:ns2="http://www.swissdec.ch/schema/sd/20130514/SalaryDeclaration"
                           xmlns="http://www.swissdec.ch/schema/sd/20130514/SalaryDeclarationConsumerContainer" etc...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am quoting from your own answer:

> As you already mentioned it just needs to be well-formed, so the
>   "faked" namespace declaration works out. I have to use version 1.0, as
>   my xsltproc seems to only support that version:

Not really, have a look [here](http://xsltransform.net/eiZQaEV). Do you see any non-numeric characters being removed?

---

Actually, it is exactly the other way round. It is the **prefix** that is arbitrary and the full namespace declaration that is uniquely identifying a namespace. Put another way, the element

```
<ns2:CustomerIdentity>
```

where xmlns:ns2="swissdec.ch/schema/sd/20130514/SalaryDeclaration"

and

```
<ns2:CustomerIdentity>
```

where xmlns:ns2="www.testing.com"

are *different* elements, as far as an XML parser is concerned. On the other hand,

```
<ns2:CustomerIdentity>
```

where xmlns:ns2="swissdec.ch/schema/sd/20130514/SalaryDeclaration"

and

```
<other:CustomerIdentity>
```

where xmlns:other="swissdec.ch/schema/sd/2013051/SalaryDeclaration"

identify the *same* element. So, when you transform an XML document and need access to individual elements, you need to declare the namespace exactly as it was in the source document, but you can choose another prefix for it.

**Stylesheet**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
  version="1.0"
  xmlns:ns2="swissdec.ch/schema/sd/20130514/SalaryDeclaration">
    <xsl:output method="xml"  encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="ns2:CustomerIdentity/text()">
        <xsl:value-of 
          select="translate(., translate(.,'0123456789',''), '')"/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

**XML Input**

```
<ns2:TaxAtSource institutionID="#SG" 
  xmlns:ns2="swissdec.ch/schema/sd/20130514/SalaryDeclaration">
    <ns2:CantonID>SG</ns2:CantonID>
    <ns2:CustomerIdentity>CHE123.456 </ns2:CustomerIdentity>
</ns2:TaxAtSource>
```

**XML Output**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ns2:TaxAtSource 
  xmlns:ns2="swissdec.ch/schema/sd/20130514/SalaryDeclaration" 
  institutionID="#SG">
   <ns2:CantonID>SG</ns2:CantonID>
   <ns2:CustomerIdentity>123456</ns2:CustomerIdentity>
</ns2:TaxAtSource>
```

Comment: You are right, and my solution removes the non-numeric from _all_ tags not only CustomerIdentity... my bad. Oh, and thanks for the link, great help!

Comment: Ok, a better one now: http://xsltransform.net/eiZQaEV/14 seems to work, but only online, my processor does not change the value.

Comment: @Chrispingu Much better! I added one more line ([here](http://xsltransform.net/eiZQaEV/15)), now it's fine. What processor are you working with?

Comment: Well ok, now with your suggestion http://xsltransform.net/eiZQaEV/17 seems to do the trick, are there any character classes one can use in transform to make it a bit more readable and error-prone?

Comment: @Chrispingu No, that does not do the trick. `translate()` only accepts single characters, not regex classes. In fact, there are none in XSLT 1.0, that's why you chanced upon the complicated solution by Dimitre Novatchev.

Comment: I'm using xsltproc from libxslt-1.1.24-19.17.1 seems a little bit old and does nothing with our xsl's (besides from reprinting all), so maybe I need another solution (needs to run with server tools)

Comment: @Chrispingu I have edited my answer again. The stylesheet _definitely_ works with libxslt, please try exactly this stylesheet and exactly the input XML in my answer.

Comment: Yes, it works with the given XML input snippet, can you give me a hint, on how to make it work with the CustomerIdentity tag more nested (I couldn't use the whole XML, I was too lazy so far to anonymize it). But don't waste too much time on my thread ;-) Thanks for your great help!

Comment: @Chrispingu It works with any level of nesting, that's the nature of functional, template-based programming. SO, it works unregarding where the element `ns2:CustomerIdentity` is in the document. But more important is that a template is applied to the element content in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the replace function of XSLT 2.0;

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0"
xmlns:ns2="www.testing.com"
exclude-result-prefixes="ns2">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />
    <xsl:template match="ns2:CustomerIdentity">
        <ns2:CustomerIdentity>
            <xsl:value-of select='replace(., "[a-zA-Z. ]+","")'/>
        </ns2:CustomerIdentity>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: If there is no namespace declaration in the XML input, no stylesheet will work. You are assuming `xmlns:ns2="www.testing.com"` but it seems there is no such declaration.

Comment: This doesn't workout with my xsltproc Tool (perl), as it seems to only support version 1.0 features => compilation error: file transform.xsl line 3 element stylesheet
xsl:version: only 1.0 features are supported

Answer (score 0):

Just as I edited my own question, I saw a way (also thanks to [xsl remove all non-numeric characters and leading 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3821741/xsl-remove-all-non-numeric-characters-and-leading-1)). As you already mentioned it just needs to be well-formed, so the "faked" namespace declaration works out. I have to use version 1.0, as my xsltproc seems to only support that version:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0"
xmlns:ns2="www.testing.com" exclude-result-prefixes="ns2">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:template match="text()">
        <xsl:variable name="vnumsOnly" select=
        "translate(., translate(.,'0123456789',''), '')
        "/>

        <xsl:value-of select=
        "substring($vnumsOnly, (substring($vnumsOnly,1,1)='1') +1)"/>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Thanks for guiding me into the right direction!

Comment: Not really. Please have a look at my answer where I am trying to explain a few things.

Comment: Leaving aside the other problems already pointed out, this attempted solution takes over irrelevant details from the source of the code; nothing in the problem as posed justifies removing a leading `1`.