# I need to update phone number in XLST to remove '+' '-' and phone extension

Tags: xml, xslt, numbers, translate

I need to transform phone numbers from the format +1 111-111-1234 x 7777777 to 11111111234 using XSLT. i have tried to use translate('+'-'-') but this is causing errors in Oxygen.

Thanks

Comment: Take a look at https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-10/#function-translate to see how translate is supposed to be used. Maybe also look at [substring-before](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-10/#function-substring-before).

Comment: A similar question was already answered: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3821741/xsl-remove-all-non-numeric-characters-and-leading-1

Comment: Did my answer help or are you still having issues?

Comment: Yes it did Daniel, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure there's a cleaner way to do this with regular expressions, but this works:

```
 <xsl:variable name="phoneNumber" select="'+1 111-111-1234 x 7777777'"/>
 <xsl:value-of select="replace(replace(substring-after(substring-before($phoneNumber,'x'),'+'),' ',''),'-','')"/>
```

So if you break it down :
substring-before 'x',
substring-after '+',
replace ' ' by '',
replace '-' by ''.

Working example: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/jz1PuPt

Comment: Yeah a bit cleaner using a regex: `replace(substring-before($phoneNumber,'x'),'\D','')`

Answer (score 0):

The signature for [`translate()`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-10/#function-translate) is: `translate(string, string, string)`

From the spec (linked above), it "*returns the first argument string with occurrences of characters in the second argument string replaced by the character at the corresponding position in the third argument string*".

So if you want to remove all characters other than numbers from a string, you first need to determine what those characters are:

```
translate(.,'0123456789','')
```

If the string value of `.` is `+1 111-111-1234 x 7777777` this results in the string `+ -- x`.

Now we can translate those characters out of `.`:

```
translate(.,'+ -- x ','')
```

What we can do though is nest the two `translate()` calls so the output of the inner call is used as the second argument string to the outer call:

```
translate(.,translate(.,'0123456789',''),'')
```

This almost gives us our desired output:

```
111111112347777777
```

but we still have the extra `7777777`. We need to get the string before `x` in the outer call...

```
translate(substring-before(.,'x'),translate(.,'0123456789',''),'')
```

this gives us our desired output:

```
11111111234
```

NOTE: We could also use the `substring-before` in the inner translate call (which results in `+ --` (notice `x` is missing)), but that doesn't really change anything in the output.

Here's a full example...

**XML Input**

```
<test>+1 111-111-1234 x 7777777</test>
```

**XSLT 1.0** (see the other answer (and my comment on that answer) for an XSLT 2.0+ option)

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="test">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:value-of select="translate(substring-before(.,'x'),
        translate(.,'0123456789',''),'')"/>      
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output**

```
<test>11111111234</test>
```

Working fiddle: http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/bwdwsf